# What is the simplest way to create an importable file in Scala?

Tags: scala, import

**TLDR**: What is the simplest way to create an importable file in `Scala`?

---

This is a beginner's question.

I've been learning `Scala` for a few weeks and now have some code that I would like to share between a couple of files/different projects. I have tried a lot of import structures but none of them worked. The requirements are:

1. File to be imported should reside in a totally different directory.
2. File to be imported should be importable by independent projects.
3. File to be imported is a single `.scala` file.
4. (Optional) file to be imported should contain `def`s, `object`s and `case classe`s.

Example:

- File to be imported location: `/some/path/to_be_imported.scala`.
- File using project (1) location: `/abc/def/will_import01.scala`.
- File using project (2) location: `/xyz/rst/will_import02.scala`.

I'm not trying to create a package or distribute it.

See how I would address this considering the programming language I already know:

---

Since I'm versed in `Python` I'll give an expected version of the answer should this problem refer o `Python`:

In that case you could:

1. Put your file on the same directory of your executed file then just run: `python3 ./your_file.py`. For instance:

   ```
   ➜  another_path|$ python3 ./main_module/main_file.py 
   1
   self printing
   ➜  another_path|$ tree .
   =======================================================================
   .
   └── main_module
       ├── main_file.py
       ├── __pycache__
       │   └── sample_file_to_be_imported.cpython-36.pyc
       └── sample_file_to_be_imported.py
   ```

   Notice that they are in the exact same directory (this contradicts point 2 above nevertheless it solves the problem).
2. Add the directory of your file to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable then run your module (best answer):

   ```
   ➜  random_path|$ PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:./sample_module python3 ./main_module/main_file.py
   1
   self printing
   =======================================================================
   ➜  random_path|$ tree .
   .
   ├── main_module
   │   └── main_file.py
   └── sample_module
       ├── __pycache__
       │   └── sample_file_to_be_imported.cpython-36.pyc
       └── sample_file_to_be_imported.py
   3 directories, 3 files
   ```

Content of the files:

```
➜  random_path|$ cat ./main_module/main_file.py 
from sample_file_to_be_imported import func1, Class01

print(func1())

x = Class01()

x.cprint()
=======================================================================
➜  random_path|$ cat ./sample_module/sample_file_to_be_imported.py 
def func1():
    return 1

class Class01():
    def cprint(self):
        print('self printing')
```

---

Edit 01: @felipe-rubin answer does not work:

```
$ scala -cp /tmp/scala_stack_exchange/ myprogram.scala
/tmp/scala_stack_exchange/path01/myprogram.scala:3: error: not found: value Timer
val x = Timer(1)
        ^
one error found
=======================================================================
➜  path01 tree /tmp/scala_stack_exchange 
/tmp/scala_stack_exchange
├── anotherpath
│   ├── Timer.class
│   └── timer.scala
└── path01
    └── myprogram.scala

2 directories, 3 files
=======================================================================
$ cat /tmp/scala_stack_exchange/anotherpath/timer.scala 
class Timer(a: Int) {

def time(): Unit = println("time this")

}
=======================================================================
$ cat /tmp/scala_stack_exchange/path01/myprogram.scala 
import anotherpath.Timer

val x = Timer(1)
x.time()
```

Comment: I never had that requierement, but AFAIK, you normally import files from the classpath, and these are either jar-archives, containing classes, or directories, containing classes, but not source files (while having access to the source files is a nice to have, too). And you use such a file in different projects, by including its classfile with "scalac -cp .:/some/x.jar:/other/dir:/mytools/lib/scala" ..." or one of many other ways to declare the classpath.

Comment: You probably should take a look at [Ammonite](http://ammonite.io/#ScalaScripts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working. Thanks for the valuable input from the other answers.

I have diversified the name of every path, file and object to be as general as possible. This probably does not follow the guidelines of the scala community but is the most explicit, illustrative help I could find. Project layout:

**File Layout**

```
$ tree /tmp/scala_stack_exchange
/tmp/scala_stack_exchange
├── anotherpath
│   ├── file_defines_class.scala
│   └── some_package_name
│       ├── MyObj.class
│       └── MyObj$.class
└── path01
    └── myprogram.scala

3 directories, 4 files
```

Where I want to run `myprogram.scala` which should import classes defined in `file_defines_class.scala`.

**Preparation**

Compile the file you want to be imported by other modules:

`cd /tmp/scala_stack_exchange/anotherpath && scalac ./file_defines_class.scala`

**Execution**

`cd /tmp/scala_stack_exchange/path01 && scala -cp /tmp/scala_stack_exchange/anotherpath/ ./myprogram.scala`

**Results**

`myobj time`

**Contents of the files**

```
// /tmp/scala_stack_exchange/path01/myprogram.scala
import some_package_name.MyObj

val x = new MyObj(10)

x.time()
```

```
// /tmp/scala_stack_exchange/anotherpath/file_defines_class.scala
package some_package_name

object MyObj

case class MyObj(i: Int) {
def time(): Unit = println("myobj time")
}
```

---

Feels like magic. However this whole process is rather cumbersome :/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to compile a .scala file with scalac:

```
Linux/OSX: scalac mypackage/Example.scala
Windows:   scalac mypackage\Example.scala
```

The above should generate a .class file (or more).

Assuming the file contains a class called *Example* you can import it somewhere else like this:

```
import mypackage.Example
```

When compiling another file which does the above import, you will need to have 'mypackage' in the classpath. You can add directories to the classpath when calling scalac by using the *-cp* flag  like:

```
Linux/OSX: scalac -cp .:path/to/folder/where/mypackage/is/located AnotherExample.scala
Windows:   scalac -cp .;path\to\folder\where\mypackage\is\located AnotherExample.scala
```

Doing this for bigger projects gets complicated, in which case you might resort to a build tool (e.g. SBT) or an IDE (e.g. IntelliJ Idea) to do the complicated work for you.

#### Other notes:

- If you don't have scalac, you can get it from the [scala website](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/) ('download binaries' option)
- the *-cp* flag stand for "classpath". There is also a *-classpath* flag which does the same thing
- Welcome to Scala :)